# how to put the text in the same line with the button

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to put the button on the same line as the text and yet,the button goes to the next line (see picture below).

[image: Preview]

My html and css (using bootstrap) is the following:

```html
<a href="#" class="mx-1 text-muted" title="Impossible to
                                    {{ selected.blabla }}
                                    or whatever">
    <div class="m-sg-list-img__item d-inline">
        <svg class="svg-icon svg-circle-cross float-right" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false">
            <use xlink:href="{% static 'svg-icons/icon-sprite.svg' %}#circle-cross"></use>
        </svg>
    </div>
</a>
```

The `d-inline` on the 4th line, used on the div class allows to have everything in a block (or I guess). The `float-right` on the 5th line allows the svg button to go to the right. Yet, it goes to the next line as you can see in the picture.

I've tried to use a `text-nowrap` in the div class, to remove the next line, to no effect. I've also tried `.justify-content-end` and also `.align-self-end` and other bootstrap tricks found [here](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-align-right-in-bootstrap-4), to no avail.

If you have any ideas, I'm all ears.

Comment: Can you create the output using Bootply/Codesandbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you need to change `div` tag to `span` tag

Here's a simple example

```html
<a>
Sample Text
<span>
<button>button(change this with your svg button)</button>
</span>
</a>
```